# Freeze slider if locator moved

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, locator, slider

I have list of many locators in my Manipulate:

```
{{listoflocs, listoflocsinit }, Locator, LocatorAutoCreate ->  True }
```

And I have a slider there:

```
Slider2D[Dynamic[ slid ], {{0, -2}, {15, 15}}]
```

I want to freeze this slider (disable it) if any locator from `listoflocs` is moved by user.
How can it be done?

Comment: Can you add a minimal working example which can reproduce the problem? Do you want to freeze it after any locator was moved, form now on?

Comment: Yes, if any locator moved, then sliders should not be able to move any more. Example (and full description of problem) was in my another question here:https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/277267/reset-button-for-manipulate-and-freezing-sliders